# Can I use the google chat image on google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-talk

I am writing an app using python on GAE. I figure since I'm using google logins as the authentication for my users, why can't I use each users google chat picture as their user portrait? However I haven't found a way to access that info. Maybe I've been using facebook api's for too long, but is there any way to access that information?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate API for retrieving a user's profile information, which unfortunately [does not currently support profile pictures](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/reference.html#Photos).